# bsearch on multiple items in struct

Tags: c, struct, binary-search, bsearch

Fixed.

## include

```
main()
{
    int n;
    int i;
    char tempMonth[255]; //Used to store the month until checked

    scanf("%d", &n);

    struct date *list;

    list = (struct date *)malloc((n * sizeof(struct date)));

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s %d %d", tempMonth, &list[i].day, &list[i].year);
        list[i].month = getMonth(tempMonth);
    }

    convertFullYear(list, n);

    qsort(list, n, sizeof(struct date), (compfn)sortDates);

    convertSmallYear(list, n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d %02d\n", months[list[i].month], list[i].day, list[i].year);
    }

    char *pos = (char*) bsearch(Jan, list, sizeof(list), sizeof(Jan), findJan);
}
```

As you can see I have put what I think is correct to call bsearch, however if it is right i'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Side note: you should really rewrote `getMonth` as a loop.

Comment: yea once i've got it fully functioning I will be doing that, just keeping it as it is because it works for now

Comment: `int Jan = 0100;` Note that this is an octal constant. Jan will be 64 decimal (which is invalid )

Comment: bsearch arg 3 is nmemb, so should be  sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]) or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're searching for a specific date, then use a `struct date` as a key:

```
struct date Jan;
Jan.month = 0;
Jan.year = 00;
Jan.day = 1;
```

Then you can use your `sortDates` function (you should rename it to `compareDates`):

```
struct date* pos = bsearch(
    &Jan, /* pointer to the structure above */
    list, /* pointer to your array */
    n, /* number of elements in your array */
    sizeof(struct date), /* size of each element */
    (compfn)sortDates /* compare function */
);
```

See also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/bsearch/ and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/bsearch for further examples.

Comment: No need to cast the return value of `bsearch`; a `void*` can be implicitly converted to any other pointer type and an explicit cast may hide subtle bugs.

Comment: @larsmans: Oops - just c&p his code and replaced `char*` with `struct date*`. Changed it.